# How to Create a Category in Calendar using Microsoft Graph API

Tags: outlook, office365

Is it possible to create a category in a calendar using a POST query with the Microsoft graph?

I'm looking  to categorize events.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Category can be set for a specific event in a calendar or you can set a color for a calendar.  But you can't set a category for a calendar.  This is consistent with the experience within Outlook.

Comment: It is not clear to me, should I be trying to us a **Category** or an **Extended property**? I also want to be able to filter my events so I can bulk delete them with a certain category or property. Which should I use?

Comment: I think Jeann Pierre means he would like to create a new category and associate his events to it.